# Getting unescaped servlet path from a HttpRequest object

Tags: java, http, rest, servlets, url-encoding

I have a custom proxy servlet that has to deal with URL-s that contain special characters (e.g. `; , . /` in their) in their path. This is because it is a RESTful application that has ugly path params by design. (Don't comment it as it is not mine.)

My client, (actually `wget`, because browsers tend to show unescaped the URL) send a request to this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApplication/proxy/foo/ugly%3Apart%2Fcomes%3Bhere/children
//note: %2F = '/', %3A = ':', %3B = ';'
```

In my servlet (mapped to `/proxy/*`) when I try to forward the GET request, I am unable to reconstruct it because `HttpRequest.getPathInfo()` returns me the URL unescaped:

http://localhost:8080/MyApplication/proxy/foo/ugly:part/comes;here/children

And therefore the information of which `/`s and `;`s were originally escaped or unescaped is lost. And that makes a difference for me, for example ; makes my URL a so called matrix URL, see http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/MatrixURIs.html, or all the REST path parameters get shifted by slashes.

Actually I found this issue on a Glassfish server, so I'm not sure if different application servers treat this differently or not. I found only this in the Servlet API:

> getPathInfo() Returns any extra path information associated with the
>   URL the client sent when it made this request.

How could I get the original, unescaped request URL that was sent by the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `HttpServletRequest`'s [`getRequestURI()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI%28%29) and [`getRequestURL()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL%28%29) methods.

If you need to remove context and servlet mappings, look at [`getContextPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath%28%29) and [`getServletPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getServletPath%28%29).